# Undefined Index, what's going on?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am using jquery form js to upload a live image. folowing is my code.

**HTML**

```
<form id="imageform" name="imageform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ajax/ajax_quotation_imageUpload.php"  >
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <label>Select Image File :</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control qimage" name="qimage">
  </div>
  <img src="images/loader2.gif" id="loader" style="display: none;">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$('.qimage').on('change', function(){ 
  $('#loader').show();
  $(".qimage").attr("disabled", "true");
  $("#imageform").ajaxForm({ 
    success:   function(data) {
      alert(data);
    } 
  }).submit();    
});
```

**PHP PAGE**

```
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['qimage']['name']);
echo $filename;
```

This is my complete code. whenever i upload file It returns Undefined qimage. where is i am getting wrong code ?

Comment: You have misspelt filenaame.

Comment: @Andy G you have misspelled misspelt

Comment: I am trying to convince the world that it is a word.

Comment: @AndyG Can you checked code. Where i misspelled file name.

Comment: @Mr.Hola Mistake is here `echo $filenaame;` in your `PHP`

Comment: Guys Can you Answer Question ?

Comment: Sorry @Zvezdas1989 i changed it but still error is Undefine index qimage not fileename

Comment: @Mr.Hola, if you are seeing undefined index error, which means that you are not getting $_FILES['qimage'], please check you ajax request headers.

Comment: It is probably because you are disabling the input before submitting the form's data.

Comment: @AndyG Yp You Are Right . Thanks

Comment: Not sure but try `$_FILES[0]['qimage']['name']` ? I think `$_FILES` is in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You disable the file-input element before submitting the form data, `$(".qimage").attr("disabled", "true");`, so its data is not submitted.

Disable it after submitting the details.

Answer (score -2):

Before HTML5 there were a bunch of techniques and plugins for jQuery to implement AJAX file uploads. HTML5 introduces FormData class that can simplify file uploads.
To construct a FormData object that contains the data from an existing , specify that form element when creating the FormData object:

var formData = new FormData(someFormElement);

For more information about FormData() follow the documentation  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

---

HTML

```
<form id="imageform" name="imageform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <label>Select Image File :</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control qimage" name="qimage">
  </div>
  <img src="images/loader2.gif" id="loader" style="display: none;">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.qimage').change(function() {
            if (window.FormData){
               var formdata = new FormData($('#imageform'));
            }else{
               var formData = $('#imageform').serialize();
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/ajax_quotation_imageUpload.php',
                data: formData,
                cache: 'false',
                success: function(res) {
                    alert(res);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['qimage']['name']);
echo $filename;
?>
```

Comment: You can't pass a jQuery object to FormData(). Also always provide an explanation. Code only answers are not very valuable without an explanation